# "Not enough changed" as 2k user, but suggested edit allowed?

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

I ran into https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19029702/1 and I attempted to edit the question to remove the set of a's since I think the OP was get past a character limit. My edit was rejected by the system with an error similar to "not enough changed". Right after that a [suggested edit was proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3009781) and ultimately approved.

It seems seems weird to me that my edit was flat out rejected by the system as a 2k+ user then someone without the edit privilege was able to get the edit into the queue. If the system does flat out reject the edit of a 2k+ user, is there some function to put it into the review queue for my peers to approve or reject?

Comment: Sure. Suggested edits can be rejected. Once at 2k, who will reject these?

Comment: @Oded if this edit was OK to be suggested but not OK to be made single-handedly, why didn't it go to the review queue as suggested? In this case 2k+ user had less privileges than <2k one and that doesn't feel right. And who would approve / reject? It's called peer review for a reason I guess ;)

Comment: I assume this is a bug, that the suggested edits and regular edits aren't judged by the automatic system equally

Comment: @Mołot - I would argue that the suggested edit should have been rejected.

Comment: @Oded rejected automatically just like single-handed edit was? OK with me :)

Comment: @RichardTingle - Actually the opposite. Because suggested edits are peer reviewed, there is more leniency in what is accepted (and bad editors will end up edit banned).

Comment: “Not enough changed?” Was the suggested edit maybe put in the queue between when you started editing and when you tried to save?

Comment: @minitech It's possible. But wouldn't Community have accepted the suggested edit in that case?

Comment: @StevenV: Maybe it’s supposed to. Suggested edits are pretty broken :D

Comment: @Oded I'll agree with the not the best edit, also not the best question and I hope it gets closed at some point (probably now will thanks to meta). But it seems odd to me that I have no recourse to allow peers to review edits since I'm "trusted" yet "untrusted" people can get something into the review queue.

Comment: @StevenV - Again, the difference is that with suggested edits, there are at least 4 people involved. Untrusted users have to get peer reviewed.

Comment: @Oded In these cases what should be the appropriate action for me be?

Comment: Make more extensive edits ;)

Comment: @Oded so why not to involve 3 more people in such cases as Steven's?

Comment: @Oded Haha, I'll agree with that. But in this case, if the content isn't there to edit, I just have to let it go even though I know it isn't constructive but I'm not untrusted enough to make it into the review queue?

Comment: @StevenV - Most posts can do with more than just minor updates. But in a case like this - don't edit, just flag/vote to close.

Comment: It is harmful to encourage people to edit more than needs to be edited. It is also harmful to encourage people _not_ to edit "content" that clearly should not be there.